# Elasticsearch Kibana logback

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logback

I am a beginner on elasticsearch and kibana, I use logback to send my logs from a java application to elasticsearch (without logstash)

I am not able to write a query in kibana because the data (json) sent by java is encapsulated in an attribute message.
here is my code java and my cofiguration
App.java

```
public class App {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String entry = "{\"firstname\":\"{}\",\"lastname\":\"{}\"}";
    logger.info(entry, "jean", "martin");
}
}
```

---

logback.xml

```
<appender name="ELASTIC"
    class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAppender">
    <url>http://localhost:9200/_bulk</url>
    <index>population</index>
    <type>entry</type>
    <errorLoggerName>es-error-logger</errorLoggerName> <!-- optional -->
    <connectTimeout>30000</connectTimeout> <!-- optional (in ms, default 30000) -->
    <errorsToStderr>false</errorsToStderr> <!-- optional (default false) -->
    <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData> <!-- optional (default false) -->
    <logsToStderr>false</logsToStderr> <!-- optional (default false) -->
    <maxQueueSize>104857600</maxQueueSize> <!-- optional (default 104857600) -->
    <maxRetries>3</maxRetries> <!-- optional (default 3) -->
    <readTimeout>30000</readTimeout> <!-- optional (in ms, default 30000) -->
    <sleepTime>250</sleepTime> <!-- optional (in ms, default 250) -->
    <rawJsonMessage>false</rawJsonMessage> <!-- optional (default false) -->
    <includeMdc>false</includeMdc> <!-- optional (default false) -->
    <maxMessageSize>100</maxMessageSize> <!-- optional (default -1 -->
    <authentication
        class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.config.BasicAuthentication" /> <!-- optional -->
    <properties>
        <property>
            <name>host</name>
            <value>${HOSTNAME}</value>
            <allowEmpty>false</allowEmpty>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>severity</name>
            <value>%level</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>thread</name>
            <value>%thread</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>stacktrace</name>
            <value>%ex</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>logger</name>
            <value>%logger</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
    <headers>
        <header>
            <name>Content-Type</name>
            <value>application/json</value>
        </header>
    </headers>
</appender>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder 
        by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ELASTIC" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

---

output console

```
 [main] INFO  com.formation.App - {"firstname":"jean","lastname":"martin"}
```

---

output Kibana/elasticsearch

```
   {
     "_index": "population",
     "_type": "entry",
     "_id": "1ILfGGABYOTxu0HReFAS",
     "_version": 1,
     "_score": null,
     "_source": {
       "@timestamp": "2017-12-02T21:16:22.551+0100",
       **"message": "{\"firstname\":\"jean\",\"lastname\":\"martin\"}",**
       "host": "MARTIN-ASUS",
       "severity": "INFO",
       "thread": "main",
       "logger": "com.formation.App"
     },
     "fields": {
       "@timestamp": [
         "2017-12-02T20:16:22.551Z"
       ]
     },
     "sort": [
       1512245782551
     ]
   }
```

---

please how to avoid elasticsearch to encapsulate the data into attribute message? and avoid logback/elastcsearch to add attribute like host, severity?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try set **rawJsonMessage** to **true**.

```
<rawJsonMessage>true</rawJsonMessage>
```

Answer (score 1):

> please how to avoid elasticsearch to encapsulate the data into attribute message?

You need to set `rawJsonMessage` to true

> and avoid logback/elastcsearch to add attribute like host, severity?

Just delete the properties from your logback.xml :

```
<property>
   <name>host</name>
   <value>${HOSTNAME}</value>
   <allowEmpty>false</allowEmpty>
</property>
<property>
   <name>severity</name>
   <value>%level</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

In ELASTIC appender need to specify another **Content-type:application/x-ndjson** :

```
<headers>
    <header>
        <name>Content-Type</name>
        <value>application/x-ndjson</value>
    </header>
</headers>
```

because to load data to Elasticsearch, using the REST API endpoint is '/_bulk' which expects the following **newline delimited JSON (NDJSON) structure**:

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```